# Ms Access form -> table synchronization

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I created a simple Ms Access Clients form, based on the Clients table.

My Clients table has the following fields:

```
ID       integer
GenderID integer
Gender   short text 
RaceID   integer
Race     short text
```

My Clients form has:

```
ClientID, 
Gender, 
Race
```

fields  (no GenderID or RaceID)

When I am entering the new record into the form, I am entering -
ID, Gender and Race no GenderID & RaceID appeared in my Clients table.

I also have 2 more related tables:

Gender:

```
GenderID
Description
```

Race:

```
RaceID
Description
```

In my Form I have a drop-down type buttons and take Race / Gender data from those 2 tables (Gender, Race)

My question -

What do I have to do (to write a query or anything else) so that if I'd enter a new record in my Form - not only the new created ID, Gender and Race would appear in the table Clients, but also - the appropriate RaceID and GenderID?

Comment: You would indeed write a query. If you try that and get stuck, we will help you.

Comment: @nicomp  Ok, I tried it before - I wrote a query - joined my Gender and Race tables with the main - Client table, by the RaceID & GenderID. It works, but if I use that "select" query type in my Form - then I can't edit or add data into the form.    But my goal - is to be able to add/modify data using the Form...       Please, advice...   Thank you!

Comment: SELECT Client.WHID, Client.DOB, Client.GenderID, Client.Gender, Client.RaceID, Client.Race, Client.LastUpdateDate
FROM Race INNER JOIN (Gender INNER JOIN Client ON Gender.DBID = Client.GenderID) ON Race.DBID = Client.RaceID;    This is it. I used mouse (visual programming), but showing what do I have in the SQL window. I also slightly modified the fields names in this topic, on Stackoverflow (there are a bit more of them in my query) But it's not the point. It works, but I still don't know how to achieve my goal ...

Comment: Should not save both GenderID and Gender (same for RaceID and Race) into tblClients. If you want to save the ID's then set up multi-column combobox with the ID column hidden. Users see the text alias but the ID is saved. Review http://datapigtechnologies.com/flashfiles/combobox3.html. Then build queries joining tables for report output.

Comment: @June7 - Thank you! Let me try, according to the link, providied!